# 1d linear regression with inequality constraint

Tags: regression, linear-model, constrained-regression

I want to solve a simple 1D linear regression problem:

$\mathbf{y} = m \mathbf{x} + c$

such that $m_{low} < m < m_{high}$ and $c_{low} < c < c_{high}$.

How can I solve this problem? Could this be framed as a linear programming problem?

Comment: You do not have to frame it as a linear programming problem. Just frame it as a standard optimization problem where the solution space of your parameters is constrained. This should work relatively fine because the SSE cost is a rather well-behaved function to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

The most straightforward way to solve a constrained regression problem is simply to re-express it as an optimization problem. Indeed most routines solving constrained least squares  pose them as [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) tasks (rather than linear) but this is a bit of an overkill for the problem you pose, a standard introductory reference would be [Practical Optimization](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122839528) by Gill, Murray, and Wright, see Sect. 4.7 on *Methods for Sum of Squares*, after that Chapt. 5 then deals with *Linear constraints*. For this simple a simple optimization routine like R's `optim` is adequate.

You simply define your cost function `myRSS`:

```
myRSS <- function(X,y,beta){ return( sum( (y - X%*%beta)^2 ) ) }
```

And then your pass it to your favourite solver (here `optim`'s `L-BGFS-B` routine):

```
bfgsOptimConst = optim(myRSS, par = c(1,1), X=newMatX, y= newVecY, 
                   method = 'L-BFGS-B', 
                   lower = c(c_low,m_low), uppper = c(c_high, m_high))
```

Just notice that you need the matrix `X` and the vectors `y` and `beta` to be of the correct dimensions ($N \times 2$, $N\times1$ and $2 \times 1$ respectively for your problem at hand), you also need to provide a feasible solution as a starting point $\beta_0$ for your solution parameters. (I used the $\beta_0 = (1,1)$ but this was just for illustration.)